# Replace a text in html tag without effecting tags attributes and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace a specific word in my code without effecting html URLs and attributes.
i tried to replace each p tag but there are some contents in div tags which also needs to be replaced.

```
$("p:not(:has(img))").each(function(){
    var b = $(this).html().replace(/oldtext/g, "newtext");
    $(this).html(b);  
});
```

Comment: show us what have you tried ?

Comment: You need to use text nodes.

Comment: sorry @SLaks i am beginner in jquery what do you mean of text nodes

Comment: @AhmedDousa: check my answer I think this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a vanilla JavaScript function for you, it doesn't change anything but the `oldtext` to the `newtext`:

```
replaceAllTextWith = function (jq, oldtxt, newtxt) {
    for (var j = 0; j < jq.length; j++) {
        var el = jq[j];
        for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var cnode = el.childNodes[i];
            if (cnode.nodeType == 3) {
                console.log(el.tagName);
                var nval = cnode.nodeValue;
                //add .toLowerCase() here if you want to consider capital letters
                if (-1 < nval.indexOf(oldtxt)) {
                    cnode.nodeValue = nval.replace(new RegExp(oldtxt, "g"), newtxt);
                }
            } else if (cnode.nodeType == 1) {
                replaceAllTextWith([cnode], oldtxt, newtxt);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

you can call it like:

```
replaceAllTextWith($("p:not(:has(img))"), "oldtext", "newtext")
```

Comment: This can _destructively_ change the HTML structure.

Comment: While using the contains is nice, it will not take into account if something is capitalized. Using text() can also destroys several parts of the html by removing the html tags of nested elements

Comment: @undefined: what if filter it to only text nodes.

Comment: thanks !! finally u saved my day, but it still not working with ie7 ill figure it out .

Answer (score 0):

this is an interesting task as jquery's `html()` displays only the html inside the selector, but not the html of a nested element

the solution is to break down the html code line by line (block) and check if there is a certain element (img) or not, in order to perform the replace.

this is the html:

```
<div id="a_unique_wrap_id">
<p><img src="https://www.google.pt/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><h1>abc</h1></p>
<p><img src="https://www.google.pt/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />def</p>
<p><h1><span><b>abc</b></span></h1></p>
<div><h1><span><b>abc</b></span></h1></div>
<div><h1><span><b>def</b></span></h1></div>
</div>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
selector=$('div');
exclude='<img';

str=(selector.html().split('\n'));
l=str.length;
output='';
for(x=0;x<l;x++){
    if(str[x].indexOf(exclude)>=0){
        output+=str[x];       
    }else output+=str[x].replace(/abc/g, "newtext");
}
$('#a_unique_wrap_id').html(output);
```

a working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/w6BfL/6/